# Flutter AppBar Icontheme change automatically?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an application. Somehow the `IconTheme.of(context).color` is changed inside an `AppBar` widget. It makes the icon becomes white on a white background.

I have a global theme with a defined IconTheme. I'm using `Color(0xFFC6426E)` as my `primaryColor`. If I change the primary color to some light color like `Color(0xFFD8EDED)`, the icon color becomes black instead. Is there any insight about it?

The `Scaffold` is routed from `Navigator.push()`, so there shouldn't be a problem from a parent widget

Here is the code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TimeLineCubit timeLineCubit = BlocProvider.of<TimeLineCubit>(context);
    AppTheme theme = BlocProvider.of<AppSettingsCubit>(context).getAppTheme();
    print("marker 0");
    print(theme.basicTheme.iconTheme.color);
    print(IconTheme.of(context).color);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children:
            [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                print("marker 1");
                print(theme.basicTheme.iconTheme.color);
                print(IconTheme.of(context).color);
                return Container();
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context)
                  .translate("timeline.title." + (isTimelineView == true ? "timeline" : "calendar")),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isTimelineView = !isTimelineView;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  child: Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      print("marker 2");
                      print(theme.basicTheme.iconTheme.color);
                      print(IconTheme.of(context).color);
                      return Icon(
                          isTimelineView == true ? AppCustomIcon.calendar_layout_24 : AppCustomIcon.timeline_layout_24);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                DateTime chosenDate = isTimelineView == true ? timeLineCubit.today : timeLineCubit.state.chosenDate;
                timeLineCubit.changeChosenDate(chosenDate);
                Navigator.of(context).push(NewDateForm.route());
              },
              child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10), child: Icon(Icons.add))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          print("marker 3");
          print(theme.basicTheme.iconTheme.color);
          print(IconTheme.of(context).color);
          return isTimelineView ? TimeLineList() : CalendarPage();
        }
      ));
  }
```

Here is the output

```
I/flutter (14349): marker 0
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): marker 3
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): marker 1
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xffffffff)
I/flutter (14349): marker 2
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xff717171)
I/flutter (14349): Color(0xffffffff)
```

Comment: The AppBar icon color within the app_bar library is White by default. It will stay white unless you manually change it through ThemeData or pass the icon color as a parameter in AppBar. It can be set like this through AppBar, IconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black), or it can be changed in the theme data class like this, ThemeData(primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)) and passed in MaterialApp widget.

Comment: I think it is not true at all. As mentioned, if I change the primary color of the ThemeData, the icon color in app bar changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why it behaves in such a way. The reason is if I don't specify appbar.icontheme, appbartheme.icontheme, it will fallback to theme.primaryIconTheme, which changed based on my primaryColor
[image: The color fallback into theme.primaryIconTheme]